# A rare property on Complete Quadrangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Studying complete quadrangulars I found an interesting question that I cannot solve:

Can the diagonal points of a complete quadrangular be collinear?

[image]

ABCD is a complete quadrangle
And the definition is:

ABCD is a complete quadrangle if A,B,C and D are 4 point wich any 3 are no collinear and the 6 lines determined by the points.

I made a mess making constructions buy found justo nonsense. Any help is welcome !

Comment: Just to be safe - what do you exactly mean by "complete quadrangulars"? If you will add a drawing to confirm my understanding, I will provide you with an elegant solution (Menelaus solution is quite messy).

Comment: A complete quadrangle (at left) and a complete quadrilateral (at right). Which one? AT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_quadrangle

Comment: Quadrangle. 
I'll add a draw to the question